# Getting error to pass # in query string value

Tags: jquery

I am getting jquery error when i am passing # contain

```
     var url = "/CheckVol/SaveItem?status=" + status + "&name=" + name ;
 $.post(url, function(data) {

});
```

here name contain 'my name # pankaj # lohani # india' , which is creating error.

Comment: Is there a reason you're putting the data in the querystring when doing a post?  Could you not just post the actual data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use spaces, #, or ? and some other character too.  In a querystring value then they must be encoded.  the # character can be encoded uisng %23.  However Nick's comment is right on.  Your already doing a post.  Why not just include your Querystring in your posted data?

You need to encode the # using %23

something like this

```
name = name.replace("#", "%23");

var url = "/CheckVol/SaveItem?status=" + status + "&name=" + name ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You *could* encode it using [`encodeURIComponent()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp), like this:

```
var url = "/CheckVol/SaveItem?status=" + encodeURIComponent(status) + 
                              "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(name);
$.post(url, function(data) { });
```

But it would be better to post the actual data, like this:

```
$.post("/CheckVol/SaveItem", { status: status, name: name }, function(data) { });
```

This requires the server looking for it here though, but it's a more appropriate solution I think.